# Google analytics different users & pageviews different for views under the same property?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an "All Website Data" view and a "Full URL" view under the same property. The "Full URL" was made by duplicating the "All Website Data" view and adding a filter so that it shows the full URL, i.e. including the domain.

["Full URL" View Filter Setup 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U3OP.png)

["Full URL" View Filter Setup 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR2Bk.png)

But I am noticing that month after month, the "All Website Data" view has a larger number of users than the "Full URL" view.

["All Website Data" View - Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQHKQ.png)

["Full URL" View - Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fasdN.png)

And when I go down to the Behaviours-->Site Content-->All Pages, I can see how the same page (for eg. about page) has two different page views values under each View.

["Full URL" View - Pageviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2QGg.png)

["All Website Data" View - Pageviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo1Be.png)

Therefore there is a difference in users, page views, and all other data between both these views, even though there is only one simple filter separating these 2 views. And almost always, the "All Website Data" view has a higher value for each metric than what I see on the "Full URL" view.

Can someone please tell me why this discrepancy may be occurring and what I can potentially do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in View Settings if the option to exlude spam bots and spiders is enabled in the View with less values:

[image]